# Solving coupled second order ODEs via Laplace transforms & Function theory.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

I have used Laplace transforms to transform a system of 2 coupled second order ODEs into 2 simultaneous equations.

1st ode:

$$\frac{3d^2y}{dt^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

2nd ode:

$$\frac{5d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}=0$$

y is a function of two variables $y(x,t)$

I define $L_t$ to be the Laplace transform wrt to $t$.

I now have an equation for ${Y_t}({s_t})$ in terms of $s_x$ and $s_t$.

1st question (now solved) is how I work out the inverse Laplace transform wrt to t $L^{-1}_t$ of functions like $s_x$ ?

2nd question (unanswered): If y is a function of x and t, does this mean that x is a function of t?

3rd question (unanswered / not clear): Why are the above differential equations PDEs not ODEs?

Updates since comments:

I made a mistake on my working (I took transforms of x also when it should have been t) - I have now got $Y_t$ in terms of $s_t$ only, and can hence solve.

Comment: I'm new to mathjax. Cleaned it up as best as I can. Not sure how to condense with less breaks between mathjax scripts

Comment: Try wrapping the tex expressions you want to remain on the same line with a single set of "\$" symbols rather than with a double set, i.e. "\$\$". For example "\$x\$" leaves $x$ on the same line. Whilst "\$\$x\$\$" creates a new line for it: $$x.$$

Comment: Also, are you sure that these equations are ODEs and not PDEs?

Comment: They are ODEs. I thought up the question myself.

Comment: I see. The problem appears not to make any sense in its current form.

Comment: Unless x is also dependant on t these definitely should be PDEs as partial derivative notation is used for functions of more than one variable

Comment: If y is a function of x and t, does this mean that x is a function of t?? For this question, why are they PDEs not ODEs?

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(x)=z(x)$ (otherwise, after the Laplace transform they look like the same functions):

$$
\begin{cases}
3\cdot\frac{\text{d}^2y(t)}{\text{d}t^2}+\frac{\text{d}z(x)}{\text{d}x}=0\\
5\cdot\frac{\text{d}^2z(x)}{\text{d}x^2}-\frac{\text{d}y(t)}{\text{d}t}=0
\end{cases}
$$

Take the Laplace transform of both sides:

-First ODE:
$$3\cdot\left(s^2\text{Y}(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)\right)+\left(s\text{Z}(s)-z(0)\right)=0$$
 -Second ODE:
$$5\cdot\left(s^2\text{Z}(s)-sz(0)-z'(0)\right)-\left(s\text{Y}(s)-y(0)\right)=0$$

Now, simplify and factor out:

-First ODE:
$$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{3sy(0)+3y'(0)+z(0)-s\text{Z}(s)}{3s^2}$$
 -Second ODE:
$$\text{Z}(s)=\frac{5sz(0)+5z'(0)+s\text{Y}(s)-y(0)}{5s^2}$$

Now, using substitution:

- For $\text{Y}(s)$:
  $$\text{Y}(s)=\frac{y(0)+15s^2y(0)+15sy'(0)-5z'(0)}{s+15s^3}$$
- For $\text{Z}(s)$:
  $$\text{Z}(s)=\frac{z(0)+15s^2z(0)+3y'(0)+15sz'(0)}{s+15s^3}$$

Now, with Inverse Laplace transform:

- For $y(t)$:
  $$y(t)=y(0)+5z'(0)\left(\cos\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{15}}\right)-1\right)+y'(0)\sqrt{15}\sin\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{15}}\right)$$
- For $z(x)$:
  $$z(x)=z(0)-3y'(0)\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{15}}\right)-1\right)+z'(0)\sqrt{15}\sin\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{15}}\right)$$